# Sorrm how to add a column to an existing table

Tags: scala, sorm

I need to add a new column to an existing table, I know I could create a new model and migrate the data over but that wouldn't be idle any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the only other way is to use some administration tool for your database to manually update the schema to match the one for the new model.

Comment: I tried that before posting, used pgAdmin 3 added the new column in the normal lower case _ format. Did a activator clean , compile etc but a Db.query[Entity].fetch didn't return added column.

Comment: Try to run your new model on a fresh database, letting it automatically generate the new schema, then just manually update your older schema to match it.

Comment: will give it a go thanks.  Going forward potentially could enchance   initMode to check for new columns added.

Comment: Just so if someone has the same problem. Add the column to the table manually, then clean eclipse even if you have automatically build checked.